# How to run tomcat in the background in windows?

Tags: windows, tomcat, process, background-process

I have downloaded tomcat from http://ftp.kddilabs.jp/infosystems/apache/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.34/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.34-windows-x64.zip.

When I execute %TOMCAT_ROOT%\bin\catalina.bat run from windows 10, it will start the process in the same window.

I want to start it in the background. Is it possible to do? I tried below options.

```
cd %TOMCAT_ROOT%\bin\

START /MIN startup.bat

START /MIN catalina.bat run

START "" startup.bat

START "" catalina.bat run

START /B startup.bat run > somefile.txt

START /B catalina.bat run > somefile.txt
```

None of these options seems to be working. Did anyone face a similar situation?

Comment: You'll have to install tomcat as a service. There's plenty of documentation available for how to do that. The concrete steps are off-topic for stackoverflow